# CSS Drop shadow how is it possible?

Tags: html, css

What technique have these guys used to get a nice melow dropshadow on the images ?

http://osc4.template-help.com/wt_32151/index.html

Comment: they use css3 shadow effect. please search it first

Comment: No need to be harsh - he just asked which property it is - box-shadow is not really intuitive name for a dropshadow/outer glow looking effect when searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
```

The property is called box-shadow but is still not implemented everywhere so you better use a crossbrowser solution. Note it's not applied on the `img` but on the `figure` tag. Can't really say but I would also put it rather on a div than on an image to avoid any possible problems.

http://snipplr.com/view/30280/box-shadow-crossbrowser/